# Override the style (color)of Lightning-button-icon on bare variant in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

Good evening,
As the title say i'm trying to override the the icon style (color) of Lightning-button-icon on bare variant in LWC, as per the documentation of salesforce there is no guidelines on the Lightning Design System for this situation.
i tried multiple button css style overrides to achieve and no success.

Take in consideration that i could do it with a aura wrapper,but with the shadow DOM of LWC i need to implement the slds and couldn't achieve it.

Code example below:

HTML:

```
<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:settings" class='icon_b' variant="bare" alternative-text="Settings" title="Settings"></lightning-button-icon>
```

CSS

```
.icon_b{--slds-c-button-brand-color:yellow;}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to override the styles? What is your aim and what is not working?

Comment: Thank for your feedback @MohithShrivastava, i changed the question and added more context, i completely agree that i should have added it. But i just want a simple colour override , but after a lot of tries i didn't find an positive way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the background

CSS

```css
.icon-b {
    --slds-c-button-color-background: yellow;
}
```

If you want to change the icon itself:

CSS

```css
.icon-b {
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground: yellow;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well i tried some varities of this and worked , thanks a lot would like this situations to be on the documentation itself.

Comment: yeah i would agree @joaocouto the docs are a bit lacking here.  Glad you were able to get it working!